# How to loop appending script in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I want to make 200 correlation combination in my data, I have this so far and its work:

```
corr = pg.pairwise_corr(df_pvt, columns=[[df_pvt.columns[0]], list(df_pvt.columns)], method='pearson')[['X','Y','r']]
corr_1 = corr.append(pg.pairwise_corr(df_pvt, columns=[[df_pvt.columns[1]], list(df_pvt.columns)], method='pearson')[['X','Y','r']])
corr_2 = corr_1.append(pg.pairwise_corr(df_pvt, columns=[[df_pvt.columns[2]], list(df_pvt.columns)], method='pearson')[['X','Y','r']])
corr_3 = corr_2.append(pg.pairwise_corr(df_pvt, columns=[[df_pvt.columns[3]], list(df_pvt.columns)], method='pearson')[['X','Y','r']])
corr_4 = corr_3.append(pg.pairwise_corr(df_pvt, columns=[[df_pvt.columns[4]], list(df_pvt.columns)], method='pearson')[['X','Y','r']])
...
corr_200
```

I need to loop this corr script so I dont have to write 200 rows of script.
I have tried this but it only have 2 combinations:

```
corr = pg.pairwise_corr(df_pvt, columns=[[df_pvt.columns[0]], list(df_pvt.columns)], method='pearson')[['X','Y','r']]
for var in list(range(1,10)):
    corr_all = corr.append(pg.pairwise_corr(df_pvt, columns=[[df_pvt.columns[var]], list(df_pvt.columns)], method='pearson')[['X','Y','r']])
    print(corr_all)
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to go:

```
with open('file.py','w') as f:
    f.write("corr_0 = pg.pairwise_corr(df_pvt, columns=[[df_pvt.columns[0]], list(df_pvt.columns)], method='pearson')[['X','Y','r']]\n")
    for n in range(1,201):
        f.write(f"corr_{n} = corr_{n-1}.append(pg.pairwise_corr(df_pvt, columns=[[df_pvt.columns[1]], list(df_pvt.columns)], method='pearson')[['X','Y','r']])\n")
```

That code will generate another python file, called `file.py`, with all 201 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

I posted my best answer earlier, but there *is* a simpler way:

```
corr_0 =  pg.pairwise_corr(df_pvt, columns=[[df_pvt.columns[0]], list(df_pvt.columns)], method='pearson')[['X','Y','r']]

for n in range(1,201):
    exec(f"corr_{n} = corr_{n-1}.append(pg.pairwise_corr(df_pvt, columns=[[df_pvt.columns[1]], list(df_pvt.columns)], method='pearson')[['X','Y','r']])")
```

**This method is not reccomended though, because it uses `exec`,  which is considered a bad practice because it's generally abused to do a task where it isn't needed, leading to potential security issues and generally bad programming.**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
corr = list()

for x in range(201):
    corr.append(pg.pairwise_corr((df_pvt, columns=[[df_pvt.columns[x]], list(df_pvt.columns)], method='pearson')[['X','Y','r']]))
```